# Unterschied zwischen "Schloss" und "Palast"?

Tags: word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *Schloss* und *Palast*?

Comment: Was hast du denn bisher darüber herausgefunden?

Comment: emm... leider - mein Deutsch ist nich gut...aber: Ich habe zwei antworten gefunden: 
1. kein unterschied
2. Palast ist ein Schloss (ein Typ)

Comment: Ich selbst verstehe unter "Palast" ein sehr, sehr großes Schloss. Das Wort "Schloss" kann auch ein kleineres Gebäude sein.

Comment: Füge doch bitte die Antworten, die Du herausgefunden hast, in der Frage hinzu, und schreibe dazu, welche Probleme Du bei den gefundenen Antworten siehst. Schönen Tag noch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich zitiere aus Wikipedia:

### Schloss

> Ein Schloss ist ein Gebäude, das im Auftrag des Landesherrn oder anderer Mitglieder des Adels errichtet wurde; es bezieht diese Bezeichnung damit unabhängig von der Größe oder der künstlerischen Gestaltung seiner Fassade. Stattliche Schlösser gingen häufig aus mittelalterlichen Burganlagen hervor, einige Schlösser gründen auch auf früheren Klöstern. Vom Ende des Mittelalters bis zu Beginn des 20. Jahrhunderts stellten die Schlösser in vielen Regionen Europas kulturelle und politische Zentren dar und werden daher heute als Baudenkmale klassifiziert.
>   [Wikipedia: *Schloss (Architektur)*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schloss_(Architektur))

### Palast

> Ein Palast ist ein in einer Stadt erbauter, schlossähnlicher und repräsentativer Prachtbau. Der Begriff „Palast“ findet sich in fast allen europäischen Sprachen wieder (z. B. spanisch palacio, italienisch palazzo, französisch palais, englisch palace, polnisch pałac, niederländisch paleis, katalanisch palau, schwedisch palats, tschechisch palác) und kann weitgehend mit dem Wort Stadtschloss gleichgesetzt werden; er beschreibt einen Wohn- und Repräsentationsbau als Residenz (Regierungs- oder Wohnsitz). Die Beschreibung als „Palast“ ist für bauliche Epochen, wie die Renaissance, oder Regionalstile und Weltgegenden, wie etwa den islamischen Raum, üblich.
>   [Wikipedia: *Palast*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palast)

### Ich fasse zusammen:

- **Schloss**
  Ein Gebäude, das im Auftrag von Adeligen erreichtet wurde. Es befindet sich in Europa. Ein Schloss muss daher weder groß noch schön sein. Es muss auch nicht als Wohngebäude dienen.
- **Palast**
  Ein prachtvolles Schloss in einer Stadt, das als Wohngebäude dient oder repräsentative Zwecke erfüllt. Ein Palast kann auch außerhalb Europas stehen.

Diese Bezeichnungen werden aber nicht durchgängig so verwendet, wie hier beschrieben. So wird z.B. das »Schloss Schönbrunn« in Wien als »Schloss« bezeichnet, obwohl es alle Kriterien für einen Palast erfüllt.

Ich glaube daher (als Ergänzung zu den beiden Wikipedia-Artikel), dass es einen weiteren Unterschied gibt:

- Alle Paläste, die im deutschsprachigen Raum stehen, werden »*Schlösser*« genannt.

Als einziges Gegenbeispiel fällt mir der *Palast der Republik* ein, der zwischen 1973 und 2008 in Berlin stand, der aber keinen adeligen Bauherrn hatte, und daher eigentlich ohnehin nicht den obigen Definitionen entspricht.

Ergänzen möchte ich noch (weil oben in den Definitionen erwähnt):

- **Burg**
  Ein bewohnbarer Wehrbau. Also ein Bauwerk, in dem man wohnen und Schutz vor Feinden finden kann.
- **Kloster**
  Ein Wohngebäude für Menschen, die ihr Leben der Ausübung eines religiösen Glaubens widmen.

Comment: Schlösser gibt es nicht nur in Europa, sosehr sie einen europäischen Ursprung haben können.

Comment: das gilt auch für Schloss Belvedere.

Comment: In der Wikipedia-Definition von "Schloß" fehlen mir zwei wesentliche Aspekte:
(1) Ein Schloß wird im Auftrag des Landesherrn oder anderer Mitglieder
des Adels errichtet, *um es (wenigstens zeitweise) selbst zu bewohnen
oder von Familienmitgliedern bewohnen zu lassen*. Ein Verwaltungsgebäude,
ein Sakralgebäude oder ein Wohngebäude für Untergebene ist kein Schloß,
auch wenn es im Auftrag des Landesherrn errichtet wurde. ...

Comment: ... (2) Ein Schloß hat grundsätzlich dekorativen und repräsentativen
Charakter. Auch wenn der Übergang von Schloß zu Burg fließend ist,
werden Gebäude, bei denen der Schutzzweck optisch im Vordergrund steht,
meist nicht als Schloß bezeichnet.

Comment: Auch ich halte die konkrete Einschränkung "Es befindet sich in Europa." für unangebracht für eine Begriffsdefinition. Das würde praktisch ausschließen, dass in Märchen, die in einer Phantasiewelt spielen, Schlösser vorkommen. Vielleicht wäre so etwas wie "Reale Beispiele finden sich (fast?) ausschließlich in Europa." zutreffender.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: 1. Nenne mir bitte (tatsächlich existierende) Schlösser, die außerhalb Europas erbaut wurden. 2. Nenne mir bitte Märchen, in denen Schlösser vorkommen, die nicht in Europa geschrieben wurden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich habe zu keinem der zwei Punkte Beispiele (habe aber auch nichts dergleichen behauptet). Mir geht es lediglich darum, dass deiner Definition nach beispielsweise das [himmlische Schloss des Riesen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_und_die_Bohnenranke) überhaupt kein Schloss sein kann, da es sich ja nicht in Europa befindet, sondern auf einer Wolke. Ebenso wäre zum Beispiel das [Schloss der Herzkönigin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_im_Wunderland) kein Schloss, da sich auch das Wunderland nicht (im herkömmlichen Sinn) in Europa befindet.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das Thema der Frage, so wie sie wohl die meisten verstanden haben, waren keine Luftschlösser, sondern reale Gebäude. In der Fantasie ist ja ohnehin alles erlaubt, da geht es ja genau darum, reale Beschränkungen außer Kraft zu setzen. Daher finde ich dein Argument ziemlich an den Haaren herbeigezogen. Ich bleibe trotzdem dabei: Jedes reales Gebäude, das auf Deutsch »Schloss« genannt wird, steht in Europa. Und als eher unwichtige Ergänzung: Wenn in der deutschen Version eines Märchens von einem *Schloss* die Rede ist, dann ist der Autor in Europa sozialisiert worden.

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Hans und die Bohnenranke ist ein 200 Jahre altes englisches Märchen, das aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach von einem Briten geschrieben wurde. (Veröffentlicht hat es ein Londoner Buchhändler, der vermutlich aber nicht der Autor war.) Alice im Wunderland ist ca. 150 Jahre alt und wurde von einem in England lebenden Briten geschrieben, der mit der *Cheshire Cat* sogar den Namen seiner Heimatgrafschaft *Cheshire* in der Geschichte verewigt, und damit den Ort der Handlung genannt hat. Alice und das Schloss der Herzkönigin sind *very British* und daher durch und durch europäisch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Wenn eine Begriffsdefinition nur so weit reicht wie die momentan existierende Welt, ist sie meines Erachtens nicht viel wert. Dann ist sie nämlich gleichbedeutend mit einer vollständigen Aufzählung aller konkreten "Instanzen", auf die der Begriff anwendbar ist. Sinn und Zweck einer inhaltlichen Begriffsdefinition ist meiner Meinung nach gerade, damit auch Unbekanntes und (noch) nicht Existierendes abzudecken. Dass unser Konzept eines Schlosses aus dem europäischen Kulturkreis stammt, streite ich überhaupt nicht ab - dass ein (reales oder fiktives) Gebäude nur als ...

Comment: ... "Schloss" bezeichnet werden kann, wenn sein (realer oder fiktiver) Standort in Europa liegt, jedoch schon.

Comment: Wikipedia kennt [Schloss Chapultepec](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schloss_Chapultepec). Das Schloss liegt im Westen von Mexiko-Stadt, stammt aber zweifellos aus dem europäischen Kulturkreis (erbaut von Bernardo de Gálvez y Madrid, Vizekönig von Neuspanien, umgebaut von Maximilian I., Kaiser von Mexiko, aus dem Haus Habsburg-Lothringen).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ah, jetzt habe ich verstanden was dich stört. Du schreibst davon, was »*als Schloss bezeichnet werden **kann***«. Weder ich, noch Wikipedia nich sonst jemand macht dir oder sonst wem Vorschriften darüber, was man als Schloss bezeichnen **kann**. Ich bezog mich darauf, was als Schloss bezeichnet **wird**.

Comment: @Uwe: Sehr interessant, danke fürs Finden dieser Ausnahme! Man könnte hier argumentieren, dass Mexiko zur Zeit der Errichtung des Gebäudes zu Spanien, und während des Umbaus zu Österreich gehört hat, und somit *irgendwie* auch zu Europa. Aber das geht dann doch ein wenig zu weit. Aber eine Verbindung zu Europa ist trotzdem nicht zu leugnen. Mich würde es auch nicht wundern, wenn es in Mittel- und Südamerika noch weitere Schlösser mit einer ähnlichen europa-nahen Geschichte gäbe.

Comment: Bei "Château Frontenac" (Quebec) wird "Château" auch gelegentlich mit "Schloss" übersetzt. Entscheidend ist m.E. eher die kulturelle Beziehung als die geographische.